# Сохранение значения переменной при перезапуске (Python)

Tags: python, переменные

Можно ли как-нибудь создать переменные, которые будут сохранять своё значение при перезапуске программы?

**Пример:** в процессе программы score = 47, после перезапуска она должна остаться такой-же

Comment: Записывайте значение в файл, при следующем запуске считывайте значение из файла

Comment: уточните вопрос (приведите минимальный пример). пока что качественный ответ дать невозможно.

Comment: @n1tr0xs пример: в процессе программы score = 47, после перезапуска она должна остаться такой-же

Comment: @andreymal я и хотел бы узнать, как

Comment: Или смените заголовок или напишите что-то типа `a = 5` и не меняйте эту переменную. При перезапуске она снова станет равной пяти:-)

Comment: @Сергей в данной программе, изначальная переменная равна 0, и постепенно по ходу программы заполняется

Comment: Запись и чтение из файла - см. примеры в конце страницы по ссылке: <https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/vstroennye-funktsii-interpretatora-python/funktsija-open/> Или вам просто нужно, чтобы вам код написали?

Comment: Про "заполняется" - я об этом и говорю. Это никак не "неизменяемая" (CONST).  Заголовок путает.